# java script game / I want to change one number by clicking on it. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, gambling

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>겜블링 게임</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid violet;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        td {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            padding: 0px;
            font: italic 50px consolas, sans-serif;
            color: blue;
            text-align: center;
            background: linen;
        }

        div#msg {
            font: italic 18px consolas, sans-serif;
            color: magenta;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        // to do
        var gameon = true; 
        var gameArray = [0, 0, 0] 
        function gen(event) {
            if (gameon == false) {
                return;
            }

            // generation 0~2 
            // to do
            else if (gameon == true) {
                
                document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
                gameArray[0] = document.getElementById("first").innerHTML;
                
                document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
                gameArray[1] = document.getElementById("second").innerHTML;
                
                document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
                gameArray[2] = document.getElementById("third").innerHTML;
                

                if (gameArray[0] == gameArray[1] && gameArray[1] == gameArray[2]) {
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Success(click here to do again)";
                    gameon = false;
                }

                else {
                    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "fail(click here to do again)";
                }
            
            }
        }

        function reset() {
            for (var i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++)
                gameArray[i] = 0;

            document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = 0;
            document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = 0;
            document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = 0;

            gameon = true;
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h3>갬블링 게임</h3>
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="first" onclick="gen(event)">0</td>
            <td id="second" onclick="gen(event)">0</td>
            <td id="third" onclick="gen(event)">0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="msg" onclick="reset()"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Each number changes to a random number from 0 to 2. If everyone gets the same number, they win.
I want to modify the (else if) part so that if I click on a number, that number will change.
The current method is that when you click, all the numbers change.
The  part needs to be solved without modification.
//What should I do to modify only the bottom part of the //to do?

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks:

- Bind event handlers in code, not in HTML
- Don't give separate `id` attributes to the `td` elements. Instead work with the container element -- the `tr` element, and its children collection.
- Use a dedicated function to perform the display
- With `event.target.cellIndex` you can know which digit was clicked (0, 1 or 2)
- The condition `game == false` can be just `!game`, since we know it is a boolean
- When this condition fails, then the only possibility left is that `game == true`, so there is no reason to check that with another `if`.
- I would add a "Reset" button to the page. It is more intuitive to click a button than to click a success message.
- Please note that if you start out with 0-0-0, and you click on a digit, there is a 1-in-3 probability that you will generate a 0, and so all three digits will be the same. This feels strange, because the user does not see anything happening, except the "Success" message.
- Don't use `innerHTML` when you are only putting plain text. In that case use `textContent` or `innerText`.
- Instead of reading the DOM with `document.getElementById` over and over again, do this once when the page loads, and place your script below the document content.

Here is suggested code. Make sure to place this script *below* your HTML content, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```js
var gameon; 
var gameArray = [0, 0, 0];

var elems = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var elems = document.getElementById("numbers").children;
for (let elem of elems) elem.addEventListener("click", gen);

var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
msg.addEventListener("click", reset);

var resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reset);

reset();

function display() {
    msg.textContent = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < gameArray.length; i++) {
        elems[i].textContent = gameArray[i];
    }
    gameon = true;
}

function gen(event) {
    if (!gameon) {
        return;
    }
    let index = event.target.cellIndex;
    gameArray[index] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    display();
    gameon = gameArray[0] != gameArray[1] || gameArray[1] != gameArray[2];
    document.getElementById("msg").textContent = 
        gameon ? "fail(click here to do again)" 
               : "Success(click here to do again)";
}

function reset() {
    gameArray.fill(0);
    display();
}
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid violet;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    font: italic 50px consolas, sans-serif;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    background: linen;
}

div#msg {
    font: italic 18px consolas, sans-serif;
    color: magenta;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3>갬블링 게임</h3>
<hr>
<table>
    <tr id="numbers">
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<div id="msg"> </div>
```

If you can only change the `else` block then make it:

```
else {
    let i = event.target.cellIndex;
    gameArray[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    document.getElementById(["first", "second", "third"][i]).textContent = gameArray[i];
    gameon = gameArray[0] != gameArray[1] || gameArray[1] != gameArray[2];
    document.getElementById("msg").textContent = 
        gameon ? "fail(click here to do again)" 
               : "Success(click here to do again)";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the good reply.
But I shouldn't fix the other part.
I can only modify the content between elseif and function reset unconditionally. Can you give me another piece of advice on what to do?

Comment: I added a section with only the changes to the `else` part, but I insist that you should improve the rest of your code according to the points I have raised.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I won't forget your kindness.